# Selecting counts with conditions and grouping

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by

Some easy points for somebody here, take the following table of data:

```
EventCode  ProcessId
---------- ---------
2          1
-6         3
42         1
-6         2
-12        2
23         4
4          2
-23        1
12         3
-26        1
```

I need a query that will get be a count of all Process ID where there is a negative event code.  So from the dataset above the result would be 3 (Process ID's 1,2 and 3 have negative event codes, process ID 4 does not)

Probably really simple, involving groups but I just can't see the wood for the trees.

As a relevant aside, there are millions of rows in this table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProcessID) FROM table
WHERE EventCode < 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.ProcessId)
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.EventCode < 0
   AND t.ProcessId IS NOT NULL
```

(It's not necessary to include the predicate on ProcessId; I do here, to point out that COUNT won't include a NULL value.)

That's the simplest approach, but not the only one.

The performance of other possible queries is really going to depend on the organization of the table (HEAP or CLUSTERED), and what indexes are available.

Answer (score 1):

In case there are multiple negative values with the same ProcessId:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProcessId) FROM table WHERE EventCode < 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the counts grouped by `ProcessId` then this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), [ProcessId] 
FROM TBL
WHERE [EventCode] < 0
GROUP BY [ProcessId]
```

If you want the entire negative count:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([ProcessId])) FROM Tbl WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE [EventCode] < 0
```

**For performance:** 
Create a filtered non-clustered index on column `EventCode` and include column `ProcessId`, where `EventCode` < 0.

Answer (score -1):

Hope you mean that:

`select count(*) from (YourTableNameHere) where EventCode < 0`